# Using ArcMap to name line segments associated to point file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

[image]I have two shapefiles, one is line segments(fiber network) and the other is points(tower locations, for example). At this time we have to manually populate the line segments from each site back to a end point(data center, for example) which leaves us with a line segment naming convention like this, S01, S01 S02, S01 S02 S03 and so on for each site that is associated with that segment.

Is there a way to do this automatically without the use of Attribute Assistant Add-In?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Could you pease provide a visual example of what you hope to accomplish?

Comment: Aaron, sure thing. This is a simple example of what I am trying to accomplish. It's a set of line segments from multiple sites(green circles) to a single site(red square). They are split up so that each green site has its own segment but as it goes back to the hub site it "picks up" the other sites on the way so the naming goes from S01 to S01 S02 and so one. Added the image above.

Comment: The segment closest to the red square will contain all of the site name associated with this set of sites.